# Is there a way to improve Rage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, rage

In Dungeons and Dragons 3.X, (and possibly Pathfinder), is there any way to 'improve' your Rage bonuses?

I know that specifically for 3.X there are a number of different forms of Rage, including:

**Ferocity:** +4/6/8 Str, +4/6/8 Dex, 4/5/6+Con round duration, −2 ranged attack rolls beyond 30 ft.
**Resiliant Rage:** +4/6/8 Dex, +4/6/8 Con, DR (1/2/3)/–

**Whirling Frenzy:** +4/6/8 Str, +2/3/4 AC and Reflex, have the option of an extra attack at full BAB in exchange for −2 attack penalty for the roundd

**Mountain Rage:** Another +2 Str on top of regular bonuses

Aside from Mountain Rage, which is the only thing I know of that actually increases your Rage 'scores,' are there any other ways to improve them besides getting the Greater and Mighty Rages later?

Comment: I think [Making an optimized Rage for d&d 3.5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30417/4563), [What all the sources of Rages per day?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150520/4563), and [Rage benefits for someone who doesn’t attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/166750/4563) cover everything you could want to know about 3.5e rage. If those answer your questions for that edition, you may want to make this just about Pathfinder.

Comment: In any event, this particular question is awkward for using both [[tag:dnd-3.5e]] and [[tag:pathfinder-1e]], since rage is so different between them (unlike almost everything else shared between them).

Comment: @KRyan the only difference between them afaik is the feat restriction is gone, and the uses/day turned into rounds/day. Otherwise both function exactly the same.

Comment: Ah, I guess the ability score increases weren't morale bonuses in 3.x as well. That does make it thorny to have both tags on it.

Comment: @willuwontu Duration, scaling, and most importantly, rage powers. They’re totally different beasts.

Comment: @AOKost Those findings should go in an answer to the question. Do not use comments to circumvent question closure, even when self-answering. I don't know if I'm just missing something, but resolving this and making it answerable should be as easy as editing the question to an appropriate scope, as the first comment here suggests. Is these some difficulty in that I'm missing? (not personally fluent in 3.5 nor PF)

Comment: @Someone_Evil I've already hit the "vote to reopen" and as far as I know (granted I don't know the intricacies of the sight) is the only way I can 'reopen' a question to actually give an answer. My question, as is, is still exactly what I want and need to know. I've found half my answers on my own, and I've yet to find anything that is what I'm interested in from Pathfinder... So unless anyone that has 'control' decides it's worth reopening, I'll give an answer... But I'd honestly rather the second question be reopened as that's showing the flaw in the system as much as an answer at this point

Comment: @Someone_Evil So, as far as I care to examine the situation I've been put in multiple times, I'm going to let things stay as they are. I'm tired of asking a question to be referred to something that doesn't answer my question and have my question closed, pointing at the 'wrong answer' as my answers by the comments... That might be petty of me, but at this point, I don't really care... I'll give what I've found as 'answers' if this is reopened... but I'm finding Stack to be more and more frustrating to use when I'm looking for answers like this... All I want is book answers, not opinions.

Comment: This question is still closed, and yet my answered question was deleted because the answers I want aren't up to the 'communities' or 'mods' standards... good work everyone!

Comment: Why does anyone need to know the specifics of how I'm going to make what I've asked for work together? You don't. I asked a book X answer, I want a book X answer. D&D has X, Pathfinder has X. Why is that so hard?

Comment: I think how you may need to consider it is that the stack isn't willing to have a combined 3.5 and PF question on this because they are two different. Since you're interested in both, you can ask a question about each. Two different systems often make things different questions. If you need a full explanation of the difference, I'm sure that'll work beautifully as a third question (we may already know it). While you're clearly interested in both, is there a particular reason I'm missing it needs to be asked together?

Comment: "I've yet to find anything that is what I'm interested in from Pathfinder" Pathfinder definitely has stuff applicable to this question, but again, that depends on how your rage works.

Comment: I actually found exactly what I was looking for, using Bloodrager Bloodlines, both the Abyssal and the Hag at level 12 give bonuses to Strength, while Abyssal increases the bonus by +4 and +6 later... Too bad I can't answer a closed question...

Comment: Those only increase the moral bonuses your rage already gives, which 3.x rage doesn't do (and thus has no effect in 3.x). There's also a number of similar things in PF that do so (which only work on PF rage). If you're using rage from PF (or if it works as listed in the class that grants it to you), that's the kind of knowledge that would clarify the question for re-opening.